# Blur effect on div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML Code that uses Bootstrap 3. So basically I use rows and columns for layout.

Now I want to give iOS like Blur behind the text in columns.

The transparency code is something like:

```
.transparent{
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  -moz-filter: blur(20px);
  -o-filter: blur(20px);
  -ms-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Now, I want to apply this in a div like:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3>Some text. </h3>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I want to blur the col-md-8 area. But unfortunately I'm ending up blurring the text too. Help needed. Thanks guys.

Comment: have a look at DEMO . like this you want???  http://jsbin.com/rabubocozo/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is one way to find a desire effect what you are looking for and that is possible using `:pseudo` element. Have a look at [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rabubocozo/1/edit?html,css,output).

Here is the CSS.

```css
div.con:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  height:90px;
  width:100%;
  z-index:0;
  left:0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  background:url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200");
}

h1{
  position:relative; 
  color:gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is this is fine absolutely, But can you like help me in doing the same for an entire background of a html. I have html background. But it overlaps body too.

Comment: I shared a concept with you. so if you want to apply blurr background on body tag then you can do like `body:after` or `body:before`. I haven't  try that, let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: Yup it worked, but reduces performance drastically. The scroll gets slow and div gets fixed. So, finally just using for the div. many thanks.

Comment: ofcourse it will be because you are applying it on whole body. if it was any portion ofcourse without adding any extra markup you can get the result..

Comment: I just want to show you that its actually possible with the help of `pseudo elements.` While other people was saying its not possible. So ideally my answer is suitable for what question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a blur filter will apply to child elements too. You should break out the text into another div, to avoid this being blurred.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately once you set a filter effect on a parent, it affects the children as well, which is too bad, but understandable. I believe the best approach would be to add another div within the .col-md-8 div, set it to fill the width and height of the .col-md-8 div, and add the blur effect. JS fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/k4o1p3u5/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="blur"></div>
        <h3>Some text. </h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
 .blur{
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  -moz-filter: blur(20px);
  -o-filter: blur(20px);
  -ms-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
  opacity: 0.7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    display: block;
}
```